# Steep cropland selection using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, classification, slope

I have:

1. a raster file of land cover classes, the classes are urban, bare land, forest and agricultural land.
2. a have a DEM, from which I can calculate the slope classes.

No I want to assign a new land cover class named steep cultivated land. The steep cultivated land is the cultivated land with slope greater than 25.

In other words, I want to divide the class named cultivated land into two classes steep cultivated land and flat cultivated land based on the slope calculated from the DEM.

How do I do this classification in ArcMap?

Comment: If you wish to also ask about ArcGIS Pro and QGIS then please ask about them in separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcMap you could:

1. Generate a [slope raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/slope.htm).
2. [Reclassify](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) the resulting slope raster such that the steep slope range = 1 and all other slopes = NoData.
3. Reclassify your land cover data such that cultivated lands = some unique value not in your land cover data, and all other values = NoData.
4. [Multiply](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/times.htm) the two reclassified datasets together.  In this operation 1 x unique_number = unique_number and any_number x NoData = Nodata.  All the pixels with a value of unique_number will be steep cultivated lands pixels.
5. Use [CON](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) to place the steep cultivated pixels back into your land cover data.